# Keras model to tensforflow

Tags: tensorflow, model, keras, h5py

Is it possible to convert a keras model (h5 file of network architecture and weights) into a tensorflow model? Or is there an equivalent function to model.save of keras in tensorflow?

Comment: You might want to look into this [blog post](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html#using-keras-models-with-tensorflow) and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/asimshankar/000b8d276f211f972168afa138eb3cc7).

Comment: Thank you very much. Those seem to be for convolutional networks, my model is sequential Dense LSTM for forecast. Any idea if it's something done before?

Comment: No, unfortunately I do not know if this has been done before. I assume that your specific architecture does not matter. A model is a model. Let us know what you find out. Might be helpful for others too. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, because Keras, since it uses Tensorflow as backend, also builds computational graph. You just need to get this graph from your Keras model.

> "Keras only uses one graph and one session. You can access the session
>   via: K.get_session(). The graph associated with it would then be:
>   K.get_session().graph."

(from fchollet: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3223#issuecomment-232745857)

Or you can save this graph in checkpoint format (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K

saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess = K.get_session()
retval = saver.save(sess, ckpt_model_name)
```

By the way, since tensorflow 13 you can use keras right from it:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras import models, layers
```

Comment: could you please update your answer - it doesn't work at all because of a lot of errors

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov, do you still need it? If yes, please give your output, what kind of errors do you get? However, algorithm is simple: you get TF session through Keras, then use this session for checkpoint saving. Or you can use it for saving model in .pb format.

Comment: finally we found some autoML solutions (when you don't need to write scripts) and decided to use them. Maybe we will return to the manual scripting in the future

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov glad to hear that you found good solution! Now there is an option to convert models to ONNX format (for inference). It supports all of the popular frameworks - keras, tf, pytorch, caffe.